# Keep the 3D Cube of Images Continue to Transition at the Same Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have used this tutorial to create a cube of images that move as a slideshow.
https://webdevtrick.com/css-3d-cube-carousel/?unapproved=16788&moderation-hash=ec78aa2bd99b49552d07f0ec60049b18#comment-16788

see what is doing https://files.fm/u/s2ywz7my

I have managed this to be automatically moved using setInterval. When the cube reached the fourth image. It moved back to the first one.

jQuery file

```
     <script>
        /** Code By Webdevtrick ( https://webdevtrick.com ) **/
        var $carousel = $('.carousel'),currentSlide, nextSlide;
        setInterval( function () 
        {
            currentSlide = $carousel.attr('data-slide');
            nextSlide = +currentSlide === 4 ? 1 : +currentSlide + 1;
            $carousel.attr('data-slide', nextSlide);
        }
        , 2000);
    </script>
```

I want the cube to continue sliding to the left and also as it is moving around itself.

Comment: I can help you but first clear these words "I want the cube to continue sliding to the left. as it is moving around itself."

Comment: Do you want to loop cube slider?

Comment: yes, I want it to loop over the images @Ibnelaiq

Comment: it seems that the code if correct.

Comment: it is moving around all the images by sliding to the left, but when it reaches the fourth image it goes back to the first image by moving back to right.

Comment: see how it slide back to the first image https://files.fm/u/s2ywz7my

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding some `CSS` and modify in `JS`, you can loop this cube slider. But it's animating by changing `data-slide` value and apply `CSS` to rotate cube. It's not dynamic slider.

**Here is working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var $carousel = $('.carousel'),
  currentSlide, nextSlide;

  $('.next').click(function() {
    if(!$carousel.hasClass('sliding')){
      currentSlide = $carousel.attr('data-slide');
      nextSlide = +currentSlide === 5 ? 0 : +currentSlide + 1;
      $carousel.attr('data-slide', nextSlide);
      $carousel.addClass('sliding');
    }
    $carousel.on('transitionend', function(){
      if(nextSlide == 5){
        $carousel.css('transition', 'none');
        $carousel.attr('data-slide', 1);
        setTimeout(function(){
          $carousel.removeAttr('style');
        },10);
      }
      $carousel.removeClass('sliding');
    });
  });

  $('.prev').click(function() {
    if(!$carousel.hasClass('sliding')){
      currentSlide = $carousel.attr('data-slide');
      nextSlide = +currentSlide === 0 ? 5 : +currentSlide - 1;
      $carousel.attr('data-slide', nextSlide);
      $carousel.addClass('sliding');
    }
    $carousel.on('transitionend', function(){
      if(nextSlide == 0){
        $carousel.css('transition', 'none');
        $carousel.attr('data-slide', 4);
        setTimeout(function(){
          $carousel.removeAttr('style');
        },10);
      }
      $carousel.removeClass('sliding');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/** Code By Webdevtrick ( https://webdevtrick.com ) **/
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-top: 200px;
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 5em;
  perspective: 100em;
}
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
.carousel[data-slide="0"] {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
.carousel[data-slide="1"] {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.carousel[data-slide="2"] {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}
.carousel[data-slide="3"] {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.carousel[data-slide="4"] {
  transform: rotateY(-270deg);
}
.carousel[data-slide="5"] {
  transform: rotateY(-360deg);
}

.slides {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  background: white;
}
.slides img {
  width: 100%;
}
.back, .slides:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateZ(-7.5em) rotateY(180deg);
}
.right, .slides:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(7.5em);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
.left, .slides:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-7.5em);
  transform-origin: center left;
}
.front, .slides:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateZ(7.5em);
}
.next, .prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  width: 6em;
  margin-top: -2.5em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #212121;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: white;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.prev:hover {
  background:  #e60023;
}
.prev {
  left: 0;
}
.next:hover {
  background:  #e60023;
}
.cf:before, .slides:before,
.cf:after,
.slides:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.cf:after, .slides:after {
  clear: both;
}
.cf, .slides {
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel" data-slide="1">
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/700?random=1" />
    </div>
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/700?random=2" />
    </div>
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/700?random=3" />
    </div>
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/700?random=4" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="next">NEXT &#8680;</div>
  <div class="prev">&#8678; PREV</div>
</div>
```

You can trigger `next` button in `setInterval` function to slide cube automatically. by adding.

```
setInterval( function () {
   $('.next').trigger('click');
},2000);
```

Comment: I don't want to include the next, back button. your first answer seems correct

Comment: You can hide buttons by adding `CSS` `display:none;`

Comment: thank you, you have given me an idea to fix my code, it works now. But I did not get why you add( sliding class)?

Comment: To stop clicking button `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` did not work. So, I have bound slide condition using `.sliding` class until animation has not been completed.